# htole32() glibc function confusion

Tags: c

I want to create the equivalent of:

```
   char* val = "\x11\x11\x11\x11";
```

using the htole32() function. How would I go about doing this since "\x11" is a nonprintable character?

**EDIT**

I'm going to be casting the int to a char* and I don't want to receive a segmentation violation, which I will get if I use:

```
    int val = 0x11111111;
```

Comment: Characters have no alignment. It's when you go the other way that problems occur.

Comment: What do printable vs. non-printable characters have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end goal is not completely clear to me, but you can specify an integer in hex format:

```
uint32_t val = 0x11111111;
```

And as noted in the comments, the hex representation can be printed out with the `printf` family of functions using `%x` (or `%X`) as the format specifier. From what I can gather from the OP, that might be what you are looking for, but I'm not completely sure.

Edit in response to the OP edit:  It's not completely clear what you mean by casting to `char*`.  If you mean you want to cast the address of `val` to char* (e.g., `char *ptr = (char*)&val;`), then that should work fine and allow you to access the individual bytes.

Comment: I'd prefer to use htole32() since it's being used in a loop I wrote.

Comment: That function accepts (and returns) uint32_t ... so I am not quite sure what you are after.  You can get the address of an integer an access the individual bytes (as char* if you want).  That by itself would not result in an access violation or segmentation fault.

Comment: I want to store the address 0x1111111 in a string in memory and be able to print it out (for comparison reasons).

Comment: Can't you just print the bytes as hex ? You just create an unsigned char* to whatever it is you want to print, and do printf("0x%02X ", foo[0]);   (and you'd print foo[1] and so on as well, depending on how many bytes you want to view)

Comment: Well in python I'd be able to do use the string += pack("<I", addr) where addr is the hex address I'd want to store but I'm not sure how to do the equivaelent in C.

Comment: @BhubhuHbuhdbus: You want to print out `"0x11111111"`?  If that's stored as an `int`, just do `printf("0x%X", val)`.  If it's a pointer, then `printf("%p", val)`.  It's still not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.